# Drupal: use blocks as pop-ups

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Is there any functionality in Drupal to make blocks appear only when I roll over a link ?

I would like to use some blocks as popups in my page.

If there isn't any, I would implement it with jQuery + CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try looking on http://www.drupalmodules.com?  It's a great site for searching for modules quickly and easily.

I quickly found a link to http://drupal.org/project/popup, which sounds like it may do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For drupal 8 users, Check this module https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_popup_blocks.

**Description:** You can turn any blocks, views, forms or anything with CSS selectors into popup.